# Streamline a MySQL Query looking for repeat orders for a given month?

Tags: mysql

So I have a script that runs each month that looks at the previous months orders and looks to see how many of those orders were placed by a matching email address from previous years to determine the number of repeat business we are getting compared to new business.

The problem is the database is growing, the business is doing better and this is taking a very long time. I assume I need to hone my skills a little bit. Looking for help to wrap my head around it.

Right now I do a simple query:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(orderid) as count, SUM(total) as revenue
FROM orders
WHERE date > '2017-05-01 00:00:00';
```

Then I just use PHP to loop through those results doing a search for any matching email address in the previous period of time.

```
SELECT email, COUNT(orderid) as count, SUM(total) as revenue
FROM orders
WHERE date < '2017-05-01 00:00:00'
AND email = $email;
```

Of course, we are getting to the point where we are doing several thousand orders a month, and we've been doing business for several years and this process is becoming incredibly slow. Is there a way to combine this into a single query to increase performance? I've looked at subqueries but it would still be running the same number of queries, would still be just as slow just more condensed. Any ideas on how to improve this?

Right now I'm just running it once and saving the results to the report database so it only is done once each month, but I figured I should take the opportunity to ask for help also to see if I can improve.

Comment: Do you have indexes on this table? I think a multi-column index on date and email (in that order) would be very beneficial.

Comment: Thanks CptMisery, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT email, COUNT(orderid) as count, SUM(total) as revenue
    FROM orders
    WHERE date < '2017-05-01 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY email) as o1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT email, COUNT(orderid) as count, SUM(total) as revenue
    FROM orders
    WHERE date >= '2017-05-01 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY email) as o2
    ON o2.email = o1.email;
```

You would just have to name your aliases properly and that's it. This will run two subqueries for both periods and if there are matches in both - you'll get a result. In order to have this as most efficient as possible, create an index where `date` is first key.

Also, if I understood you correctly, second sub-query could not even include grouping if you're looking just for emails that have placed an order in the latest period, therefore your query could look like that:

```
SELECT o1.email, COUNT(o1.orderid) as count, SUM(o1.total) as revenue
FROM orders as o1
WHERE o1.date < '2017-05-01 00:00:00'
AND EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM orders AS o2
            WHERE o2.email = o1.email
            AND o2.date >= '2017-05-01 00:00:00')
GROUP BY o1.email;
```

Comment: This appears to be very slow, at least as slow as the way I'm doing it.

Comment: Are Indexes in place?

Comment: Indexes are a bit over my head I think. It's an innodb database and when I tried to run indexes on the Date and the Email, it ran forever and finally brought the table to be completely non-responsive. There are 116,000 rows and either it doesn't handle it well or I'm beyond my ability (or both). I think it's best if I just deal with it being slow for now.

Comment: Have you tried storing users emails, that placed an order in a separate table? Where email would be a primary key, then you would have to make a simple join with that new table with the actual one that has all orders. This is some overhead, but might be worth it

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT 
    new_orders.email, 
    COUNT(new_orders.orderid) as count, 
    SUM(new_orders.total) as revenue
FROM 
    orders new_orders
    join (select distinct email from orders where old_orders.date <= '2017-05-01 00:00:00') old_orders on old_orders.email = new_orders.email 
WHERE
    new_orders.date > '2017-05-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY
    new_orders.email
```

Comment: This appears to be faster, but I'm getting different results. Like way different results that don't make sense. An extra 30 orders plus an extra $6k in revenue which isn't even close to our average order value. I appreciate the response but I'll have to stick to the tried and true.

Comment: I think you're correct, I think the query as originally written is including the old transactions in the count and the sum and needs to be tweaked.

Comment: I modified the original query.  I think the new one should work.

Comment: This didn't work either. Doing it manually I came up with 550 orders and $25k of revenue. Your first query brought back 585 orders and $31k of revenue, and I don't think it was just extra orders because our orders don't average that high per order. Now your second query returns 300 orders and I forgot the revenue, but I'll just stick with the manual method, I know the process is solid on that even if it's slow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a nested query?

Although you're scanning the same data, there is an overhead with returning the first result set to PHP, and each subsequent query.

With a nested query you avoid this, and allow the database to make its own internal optimisations, which can be significant.